# VB.NET and Java Web Service - Adding a Header element doesnt' give expected results

Tags: vb.net, soap, header

I'm having a lot of headache with the problem described in this topic title.
I'm not very good with web services and I'm dealing with one developed internally in Java.
This web service requires a Header element named Token with a value (an encrypted string).
I've been able to add this "Token" but the service doesn't accept it.

This is the request xml my proxy calls generates (proxy class built with WSDL.EXE and modified to accept a SoapHeader external class I wrote to add Header to request):

```
<soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Header>
        <TokenHeader soap:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next">
            <Token>[TOKEN VALUE]</Token>
        </TokenHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and this is what the web services wants (this is a xml request made by a java tyest client):

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns1:Token soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
            [TOKEN VALUE]
        </ns1:Token></soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(Namespace:=[WSDL NAMESPACE])> _
Public Class TokenHeader
    Inherits SoapHeader

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Token", Namespace:=[WSDL NAMESPACE])> _
    Public Token As String

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.Actor = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next"
    End Sub
End Class
```

and this is the piece of code of the proxy class where I've declared the Token

```
<System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)> _
<WebMethod(), SoapHeaderAttribute("TokenHeader", Direction:=SoapHeaderDirection.In)> _
Public Function ChiamaEdicola(<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:=[WSDL NAMESPACE])> ByVal ChiamaEdicolaRequest As ChiamaEdicolaRequest) As <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ChiamaEdicolaResponse", [Namespace]:=[WSDL NAMESPACE])> ChiamaEdicolaResponse
    Try
        Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("ChiamaEdicola", New Object() {ChiamaEdicolaRequest})
        Return CType(results(0), ChiamaEdicolaResponse)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Errore: " & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Finally the piece of code where I call this function:

```
Private Sub SendRivData(ByVal IRWebSrvData As ChiamaEdicola)
Dim IRWebSrvSend As New ChiamaEdicolaRequest
Dim IRWebSrvRecv As ChiamaEdicolaResponse
Dim IRWebSrvClient As New EdicolaService
Dim TokenHeader As New IR2IG.TokenHeader

    IRWebSrvSend.ChiamaEdicola = IRWebSrvData

    TokenHeader.Token = "[TOKEN VALUE]"
    IRWebSrvClient.TokenHeader = TokenHeader

    IRWebSrvRecv = IRWebSrvClient.ChiamaEdicola(IRWebSrvSend)

    If IRWebSrvRecv Is Nothing Then 
        MsgBox("Errore durante l'elaborazione!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With IRWebSrvRecv
        If CInt(.Stato) <> 0 Then
            MsgBox("Elaborazione OK:" & vbCrLf & .Messaggio, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("Errore durante l'elaborazione:" & vbCrLf & .Messaggio, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This is all (I had to omit few parts because my boss doesn't want me to make them public).

If someone knows how to accomplish this, please, help me. 
It's about 4 days I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mess with the generated proxy class but instead extend this class and give your own implementation, in your case override `GetWriterForMessage` and add your required header to the message e.g. The following code is just to give you the idea how to fit the pieces:

```
Public Class ExtendedWebService
     Inherits myWebService

     Protected Overrides Function GetWriterForMessage(message As SoapClientMessage, bufferSize As Integer) As System.Xml.XmlWriter

         message.Headers.Add(YourCustomHeader)

         Return MyBase.GetWriterForMessage(message, bufferSize)
     End Function

End Class
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is it possible to add a cutom header without using a custom class for it? Because if I try to modify the GetWriterForMessage with my custom header the situation doesn't change

Comment: Ok, I've done a little change to my custom SoapHeader class. Adding <XmlTextAttribute()> to my Token public string and the GetWriterForMessage made it! Thanks!